# How to pass state as props so you can modify them

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a main class here that holds three states rendering a Form component:

```
class MainApp extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     fName: '',
     lName: '',
     email: ''
 }

render(){
  return(
     <div className="content">
          <Form formState={this.state}/>
     </div>
  )
}
}
```

And then inside my Form component I have ff codes:

```
class Form extends React.Component{
     constructor(props){
       super(props);

     }

    render(){
      return(
         <form>
            <input placeholder="First Name" value={this.props.formState.fName}
             onChange={e => this.setState({ this.props.formState.fName: e.target.value })}
         </form>
      )
    }
    }
```

Upon running this codes, I got an error saying it cannot read the property 'fName' of null.

How do I properly pass one state to it's children component so it can modify the main one?

Comment: Your constructor in `MainApp` is not closed

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit parent's state directly from child component. You should define handlers that would change parent's state in parent component itself, and pass them to children via props.

Parent:

```
class MainApp extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     fName: '',
     lName: '',
     email: ''
   }

   fNameOnChange = (value) => {
     this.setState({fName:value})
   }

   render(){
     return(
       <div className="content">
         <Form formState={this.state} fNameChange={this.fNameOnChange}/>
       </div>
     )
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class Form extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
 }

 render(){
   return(
      <form>
        <input placeholder="First Name" value={this.props.formState.fName}
        onChange={e => this.props.fNameChange(e.target.value))}
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        class MainApp extends React.Component{
         constructor(props){
           super(props);

           this.state = {
             fName: '',
             lName: '',
             email: ''
         }
          this._handleChange = this._handleChange.bind(this);
        }

     //dynamically update the state value using name 

      _handleChange(e) {
            const { name, value } = e.target;
            this.setState({
                [name]: value
            });
        }

        render(){
          return(
             <div className="content">
                //You can pass state and onchange function as params
                  <Form formState={this.state} _handleChange={this._handleChange}/>
             </div>
          )
        }
        }



   class Form extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
          super(props);
       }

        render(){
           return(
            <form>
                <input placeholder="First Name"
                 defaultValue={this.props.formState.fName} 
                 id="fName"
                 name="fName"
                 onChange={e => this.props._handleChange} />
            </form>
         )
       }
     }
```

Comment: I like this approach however I can't type anything on the textbox.

Comment: @JonDobie The code should have bound to `defaultValue`, not `value`.  I fixed the code sample.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass a function as a prop to update the state of parent component. It is advised not to change props directly.

In your parent class write a function like:

```
onChangeHandler (data) {
  this.setState({fname: data})
}
```

And pass it to the child component and you can call this method as 
`this.props.onChangeHandler(event.target.data)`
from child component.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you want to pass a `formState` to the form itself. The form should manage is own state. It is not a good practice to do 2 way binding like the Form mutate the MainApp's state

However, if for some reasons you need a copy of you `formState` in your `MainApp` component, then your `Form` component should have an `onSubmit` callback method.

```js
class MainApp extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      form: null
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="content">
        <Form onSubmit={(form) => {
          this.setState({ form });
        })}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      fName: '',
      lName: '',
      email: ''
    }
  }


  render(){
    return(
        <form onSubmit={e => this.props.onSubmit(this.state) }>
          <input placeholder="First Name" value={this.props.formState.fName}
            onChange={e => this.setState({ this.props.formState.fName: e.target.value })}
        </form>
    )
  }
}
```